# How do you change what a like/send button posts to a facebook wall?

Tags: javascript, facebook, meta

I'm working on a not for profit website, and trying to integrate with facebook.  The app seems to work fine, single sign on works fine, even a custom "post to wall" function works fine using the javascript sdk.  What does not work, however, is adding a photo to represent the entity, and anything other than default text, when a person clicks on the like button.

What's worse is there is some ghost text that I personally have never actually seen (other than in the text box itself) that finds its way into the dialog box when posting and leaving the text box empty.

The documentation here falls short:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Open Graph API tags also did nothing.

If you "like" the "like button" you'll see that their example does exactly what I'm trying to accomplish.  There's a photo and a little description of what the button is.  Is it possible to do this on other sites?

Comment: You can use the Facebook debugger to check what Facebook sees on your site: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug . It is the meta tags that you use in order to change texts etc on likes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've struggled a lot with this myself, but I found that by putting my page's URL into [Facebook's debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), it made the correct image, text, etc. show up when clicking a share button.

Comment: You and Robin above helped solve the problem.  The debugger showed me that FB was, in fact, pulling nonexistent meta data from my blank under construction page.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add these tags in your pages'  tags.

```
<html xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
    <head>
        <meta property="og:title" content="insert your title here"/>
        <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
        <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/foo/"/>
        <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/images/example.jpg"/>
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="A human-readable name for your site">
        <meta property="og:description" content="A one to two sentence description of your page">
    </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To turn your web pages into graph objects, you'll need to add Open Graph protocol  tags and the Like button to your webpages.

Instructions are here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/